# Python - Increment file by 1

Tags: python, file, hex, byte

I have a file with the following hex values:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

What I want to do is essentially increment this file by one. i.e. after running the program, I will be left with:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01
```

And when I get to:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF
```

I want the next increment to leave me with:

```
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
```

Is there a simple way to do this with a byte array, or something similar?

EDIT:

This is something like my previous code:

```
filename  = 'file'

with open(filename, "rb+") as file:
    seek = -1
    while True:
        file.seek(seek, 2)
        value = file.read(1).encode('hex')
        file.seek(seek, 2)
        if value != 0xFF:
            file.write(str(int(value, 16) + 0x1))
            break
        else:
            file.write(str(0x00))
            seek -= 1
```

It gives... unexpected results.

Comment: Yes there are ways to do this, what have you tried so far?  Please post your code.

Comment: the idea here @ SO is that you will try something, post that code and ask us why/how it failed - not 'send me the codez'........

Comment: Does the file contain 8 bytes with the value `0` or does it contain the string `"00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"`?

Comment: I'm putting my code together. This is something I tried writing a while ago and thought about just recently.

Comment: Matthias - As mentioned in my original question, the file contains the hex values 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Comment: Code is now added. I'm thinking I need to look at a completely different method. As I asked previously, would a byte array be better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Python3, you can use `int.from_bytes()` and `int.to_bytes()`:

```
filename = 'file'

with open(filename, "rb") as data_file:
    data = data_file.read()
    length = len(data)
    data = int.from_bytes(data, 'big')

data += 1

with open(filename, "wb") as data_file:
    data = data.to_bytes(length, 'big')
    data_file.write(data)
```

Comment: Perfect. Very much what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the contents of the file to an integer first, then increment the integer, and write the integer as hex to the file

`value = int('0x' + open(filename,'r').read())
value += 1
open(filename, 'w').write(str(hex(value)).replace('0x','')`

Comment: The file doesn't actually contain those characters, per my understanding of the comments; OP is just writing out a hex dump representation of the (binary) file.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The OP has, e.g., `file.write(str(0x00))` in his example code. I'm lead to think that he's writing a string representing his integer, built piece by biece.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the total number of bytes in the file, you can read the whole thing into a `bytearray` or `bytes` object, then pass that to `struct.unpack()`.  But that won't work for anything larger than 64 bits (8 bytes), and if the number of bytes is not a power of 2, you'll need to pad it.

In the more general case, you can use bitwise operations to suck the number into memory reasonably simply:

```
number = 0
while True:
    next_byte = f.read(1)
    if next_byte == b'':
        break
    number <<= 8
    number |= next_byte[0]
```

Unfortunately, writing it back out is slightly less straightforward:

```
import io
scratch = io.BytesIO()
while number:
    scratch.write(number & 0xFF)
    number >>= 8
data = scratch.value()[::-1]
f.write(data)
```

Comment: The number of bytes can vary. I have come up with another solution (I shall post in a moment), but I shall look at your answer as it seems like it could be more efficient than mine.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with an answer based on my previous attempt:

```
import binascii
filename  = 'file'

with open(filename, "rb+") as file:
    seek = -1
    while True:
        file.seek(seek, 2)
        value = file.read(1).encode('hex')
        file.seek(seek, 2)
        if value != 'ff':
            hb = binascii.a2b_hex("%02x" % (int(value, 16) + 0x01))
            file.write(hb)
            break
        else:
            file.write(binascii.a2b_hex('00'))
            seek -= 1
```

I don't like it, but it works for now.

I would like to see better answers, if possible? :)

Answer (score 0):

Your Q is not completely clear, but I have that your file contains initially 24 characters `'0' '0' ' ' ... ' ' '0' '0' 'LF'`.

If I have it right, you can read the signature from the file as a string, pass it to the below function and write, wherever you want, the string that it's returned.

```
def hex_incr(str):
    hl = str.split()
    num = 1
    for i, h in enumerate(hl):
        num += int(h,16)*256**(7-i)
    rep = "%016X"%(num,)
    return " ".join([rep[i:i+2] for i in range (0,16,2)])
```

I have also some testing

```
print hex_incr("00 00 00 00 00 10 01 01")
print hex_incr("00 00 00 00 00 00 00 FF")
print hex_incr("00 00 00 00 00 10 FF FF")
print hex_incr("00 00 00 00 0D 10 01 01")
```

that produces

```
00 00 00 00 00 10 01 02
00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
00 00 00 00 00 11 00 00
00 00 00 00 0D 10 01 02
```

#### The eagerly awaited one-liner

```
def hex_incr(s): return " ".join([r[i:i+2] for r in ["%016X" % (1 + int("".join(s.split()), 16),)] for i in range(0,16,2)])
```